# What does the "?" mean in the following statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Forgive my "newbie" question, but what the heck does the question mark, "?" mean in the fololowing line of code?

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = (editing) ?
    NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done") : NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a ternary statement, the `?` is the conditional operator. The statement is basically saying:

```
if (editing) {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
} else {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
}
```

You could think of it like:

`?` - If previous statement is true, do code immediately after.

`:` - Else / Otherwise, run the code immediately after this.

You can read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation. You will find that this construct is available in many languages other than C / Objective-C.

Comment: This is a good answer; I'd just like to point out that, strictly speaking, this is the "conditional operator"; although it is _commonly_ know as "ternary", "ternary" simply means "takes three operands".

Answer (score 4):

It is called ternary operator, it's like an if statement but in one line.

It is like :

```
if (editing)
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
else
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the conditional operator: `x = a ? b : c`. If `a` is true, it assignes `b` to `x`, otherwise it assigns `c`.

Answer (score 3):

It's called the [Ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

What it means is that, given the following code:

```
(condition) ? a : b
```

The code will execute `a` if `condition` is `true`, and `b` otherwise.

In your case, the code will behave the same as if you were to write:

```
if (editing) {
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
} else {
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

its a short if statement

in the code below the statement 1 > 0 is checked, if its true the first set will be executed, after the "?" if its false it will run the code behind the ":"

```
(1 > 0)? true: false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator is used http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#The_Ternary_Operator.
It means that title will be initialised with NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done") if editing variable is TRUE and with NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit") otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse

This can be read as

```
if (editing)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Done", @"Done");
else
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Edit", @"Edit");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ternary operation. Take a look at following explanation in wikipedia — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript

Answer (score 1):

This has obviously been answered (thoroughly) above but I'm throwing my hat in (for the off chance someone just learning programming happens to stumble upon this):

Here is my plain english definition of a ternary statement(what this is)

```
Variable = what_to_check ? true_value : false_value;
```

is saying:

is what_to_check true? okay then, set Variable to true_value. If not, set Variable to false_value.