# Can anyone help me to understand this? ------ ( )? [ ]:[ ] in objectiveC

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the question mark and the colon (?: ternary operator) mean in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595392/what-does-the-question-mark-and-the-colon-ternary-operator-mean-in-objectiv)

```
    NSString *requestString = (self.isFirstTimeDownload) ? [NSString stringWithFormat:[self.commonModel.apiURLs objectForKey:@"updateNewsVerPOST"],@""] : [NSString stringWithFormat:[self.commonModel.apiURLs objectForKey:@"updateNewsVerPOST"], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"localnewsupdate"]];
```

Can anyone help me to understand what this is ()?  and  :  in Objective-c?
Thank you!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the question mark and the colon (?: ternary operator) mean in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2595392/), [What does this mean: NSString *string = NO ? @“aaa” : @“bbb”;](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8290073/), [Don't understand this syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12132665/), [Objective-C operator (?) and (:)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11705848/), [What does the “?” mean in the following statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5832134/), [inactive ? @“inactive”: @“active” syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10239632/),

Answer (score 4):

That's a ternary operator.

Example:

```
  bool foo(int i)
  {
      if ( i > 5 ) 
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }
```

is equivalent to

```
  bool foo(int i)
  {
      return ( i > 5 ) ? true : false;
  }
```

You can omit the first operand: `x ? : b` in which case, the value of the expression is x when x is non zero, or b otherwise. Example:

```
int i = 1;
i = 2 ? : 3;   // equivalent to i = 2; (because 2 is non zero)
i = YES ? : 3; // equivalent to i = 1; (because YES is 0x01, which is not zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a):

```
NSString *requestString = ( boolean condition ) ? @"valueIfTrue" : @"valueIfFalse";
```